# DefaultFromTemplate method

Tags: acumatica

I want to use the DefaultFromTemplate method on the PX.Objects.PM.ProjectEntry graph, but it is protected. (C#.net)

Is there a way I can make this public or extend the graph maybe.  Or do I have to copy the code into my own class?

cheers

Comment: Where do you need to call it? You could simply created an inherited version of ProjectEntry graph, and add a public method that simply calls the protected version. Be warned that since this is an internal method, it could change in the future, and thereby your customization would stop compiling.

Answer (score 0):

At this stage I'm just inheriting the project entry graph and calling it through a public method.  cheers